# What are regions summary comments in C# source code?

Tags: c#

I know what is attributes in C#, but I don't know what are those text. I never see them in any C# language textbook.

Can you help me explain what is the text in the code?

What are their purpose? Can I safely delete them?

1. ///
2. #region

[image]

Comment: `//` is used for comments.

Comment: triple slash is summary and people see it when they use your library

Comment: Comments preceded by three slashes `///` are for documentation. Visual studio will process these comments to produce documentation for you.

Comment: "I never see them in any C# language textbook." That suggests you have the wrong books. I'd be surprised to see any introductory book on C# that doesn't at least describe comments. Regions are *slightly* more obscure, but a search for "#region c#" gives good results...

Comment: @JonSkeet Comments are different from what OP is asking about, comments use two slashes, three slashes define documentation XML.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, but I'd expect any book talking about C# comments to describe XML comments as well, at least briefly. (They *are* still comments.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't remember XML comments covered in my college text books, but this was some time ago of course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`#region`

lets you specify a block of code that you can expand or collapse when using the outlining feature of the Visual Studio Code Editor. In longer code files, it is convenient to be able to collapse or hide one or more regions so that you can focus on the part of the file that you are currently working on.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek.aspx

`/// comments`

In Visual C# you can create documentation for your code by including XML elements in special comment fields (indicated by triple slashes) in the source code directly before the code block to which the comments refer.

When you compile with the /doc option, the compiler will search for all XML tags in the source code and create an XML documentation file. To create the final documentation based on the compiler-generated file, you can create a custom tool or use a tool such as [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/).

Also, Visual Studio intellisense will use this information to show to the consumer of your public APIs as description. Like if you have descriptions about an input argument, the comments you mention for that argument will be displayed to the user trying to call that function in Visual Studio like the image below:

[image]

Comment: You might add that intellisense will use the information in those /// comments in the help it displays.

Comment: So much thanks! It helps me clear the question! @Aram

Answer (score 1):

The cooments [xmldocs comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx). You can safely delete them, if you want to, of course.

Regions are text "helpers" which help you to [specify outlining](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek.aspx) of your code.

Comment: xmldocs is the right answer, but your answer would be much better if you mentioned a little about how they are useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
/// is for auto-generated documentation
```

Yes, it's safe to delete.  [Microsoft documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7(v=vs.100).aspx).

`#region` and `#endregion` can be safely deleted if you delete just these tags (not the code in between)

Answer (score 0):

Yes both can safely be deleted without any damage to the code, so long as you delete just the `#region` and `#endregion` tags and not the code between.

Regions are just what the name implies, a region of code that does a specific thing, for instance in many controllers you see a `Create`, `Read`, `Update`, and `Delete` region, to define where the code for CRUD operations goes, this also allows you to collapse a whole region in VS and likely other IDEs as well, to better view only what you want to see, makes navigating code easier.

Three slashes `///` are used to define the XML documentation on classes, properties and methods. VS has the option to output this on a build to an XML document, then there are other tools that can be used to make that XML easier to use. The summary also shows up as the tooltip when you hover over usages of those classes, methods and properties in VS, to make it easier to understand the function of the methods and classes without reading over the code.

Neither is actually vital to the code, but they are helpful to developers that are looking at the code, even the same person who wrote the code can get use out of XML comments when coming back to something they did months ago.